# How to use rbhive gem and query hive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hadoop, hive, rbhive

I have a task to query in a hive db from ruby code. I am planning to use [rbhive](https://github.com/forward3d/rbhive) gem, but from it documentation, I am not able to get how to pass username, password, db name, etc when connecting to hive server.

Here is my code:

```
res = RBHive.connect('host_address', 10_000) do |connection|
  connection.fetch 'show databases;'
end
```

It just shows:

```
Connecting to host_server on port 10000
Executing Hive Query: show databases;
```

and it hangs there indefinitely.

Comment: did you resolve this issue?

Comment: No, provided answers etc did not work, I used some other script to get data.

Comment: @Saurabh Can you help me to connect Hive from rails 5 application ? I am not able to install the gem itself.

Answer (score 4):

That may be surprising, but with Hive 1.0.0 I managed to connect using

```
RBHive.tcli_connect('host', 10000, {transport: :sasl, sasl_params:{}}) do |connection|
```

Comment: @Lukasz Could you please metion what are the sasl_params we can pass ?

Comment: How to pass database name ?

Answer (score 2):

Please use

```
options = { username: 'username', password: 'password' }
RBHive.tcli_connect('host', 'port', { transport: :sasl, sasl_params: options}) do |connection|
  results = connection.execute "SHOW DATABASES"
end
```